# Scrape a data from a html table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm try to scrape a table, from [B3 site](http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp?Data=31/08/2020&Data1=20200831&slcTaxa=PRE), but the result is a empty data frame.

What's wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
url = "http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp?Data=31/08/2020&Data1=20200831&slcTaxa=PRE"
df  = pd.read_html(io=url)
print (df)
```

Comment: Maybe the site blocks user-agent that comes from a bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default parser for `read_html` is lxml, which is not able to parse your document. Switching to html5lib (Beautifulsoup 4) does the trick.

Below is your code with the addition of [a flavor parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html).

```
import pandas as pd
url = "http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp?Data=31/08/2020&Data1=20200831&slcTaxa=PRE"
df  = pd.read_html(io=url, flavor='bs4')
print (df)

[    Dias Corridos  DI x pré       
    Dias Corridos 252(2)(4) 360(1)
0               1       190      0
1               8       191    171
2              11       191    199
283         10760       848    832
284         10801       848    832
285         10941       848    833
286         12677       854    838

[287 rows x 3 columns]]
```